# Express.js, Node.js, EJS - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

1) My index page with ejs:

```
 <%include ../includes/layout.ejs %>
 <h1>This is the index page, did layout come along?</h1>
```

2) My layout pages with ejs:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html>
 <head>
    <title>MultiVision</title> 
    <% include ../includes/styles.ejs %>
    <script type="text/javascript" rc="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <%include ../includes/scripts.ejs%>
</body> 
</html>
```

3) My scripts page with ejs:

```
 <script src="/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="/vendor/toastr/toastr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/vendor/angular/angular.js"type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="/app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, I consistently receive this error for each of the script tags:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  ######.js
```

Changing them to a cdn location works though, but that is not what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I guess it would help if I had included this in my server.js: ;)**

> ```
>   ....
>   , path = require('path'),
>   .....
>   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
> ```

Comment: I found this helpful and it also fixed my issue.  I'm having a hard time understanding why this was needed though?

Comment: The `*.js` files weren't set up to be statically served, and so instead the server was returning a 404 error which the browser tried to parse as JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, was finally able to serve a webpack generated bundle using this statement.