# ExpressJS, EJS: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at file.js 1:1

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a ExpressJS server with ejs template engine runs a Blockly app and a threejs map in a web page. My problem is that, when I go to /applications/newApp, app.ejs works well but when I go to /applications/:slug (this is a request to load a saved application) the app.ejs crashes with error below:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at file.js:1:1)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at anotherFile.js:1:1)
```

Here is my ejs codes:

```
    <p hidden id="pageName">
      <% if(page_name=="savedApp" ) { %>
        savedApp
        <% } else { %>
          newApp
          <% } %>
    </p>

    <p hidden id="slug">
      <% if(page_name=="savedApp" ) { %>
        <%= slug %>
        <% } else { %>
          none
          <% } %>
    </p>
```

these both calles same file but one works well while another crashes. These are also how server responses;

```
exports.getNewApp = (req, res) => {
    res.render('app', {
        page_name: 'newApp',
    });
};
```

```
exports.loadApplication = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.render('a', {
            page_name: 'savedApp',
            slug: req.params.slug,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500);
    }
};
```

WHAT I TRIED:

- I checked the opened <% %> tags, there is no error in here
- I am using public files like that:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public')));
app.use('/applications', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public/blocklyApplication')));
```

And I also checked following questions:

[Express.js, Node.js, EJS - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234921/express-js-node-js-ejs-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

[SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; while compiling ejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815247/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-while-compiling-ejs)

[SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,while compiling ejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743630/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-while-compiling-ejs)

I don't get that, they are both responses same page with common url, one works well other doesnt. What should I check?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, after trying some changes in code, adding

```
app.use(
  '/applications/:slug',
  express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public/blocklyApplication'))
);
```

in my code makes everything work.

EDIT: and also in here [Express-js can't GET my static files, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why) there is a detailed answer about routed public.